# Difference between home_url() versus get_option('home')

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to echo out my website's URL. I read through WordPress Codex but I still do not understand, what is the difference between

```
<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>

versus

<?php echo home_url(); ?>
```

Is one "safer" to use? Which one should I use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both the functions will do the same thing but there is a difference in how they do it.

For instance `home_url()` will internally call `get_option('home')` and add appropriate protocols like http or https. And `get_option('home')` will return the raw value of your set URL without making any alternations.

Also, it is recommended that you use `home_url()` because its more secure.

Comment: Thanks that helps me understand. --- Another question. If I need to link to an "About Us" page would I do it like this: `<?php echo esc_url( home_url() ); ?>/about-us/` ----- And is it suggested to use the escape the URL version: `<?php echo esc_url( home_url() ); ?>`

Comment: @leko The proper way of doing that will be `get_permalink( get_page_by_title( 'About Us' ) )`

Comment: Thanks Jay. Also, does home_url need to be escaped? `<?php echo esc_url( home_url() ); ?>`

Comment: @leko  Yes its a better practice but sometimes it might cause problems like when your passing arguments.

Comment: I see. One more question. Although it is not proper, is there any consequence to linking this way: `<?php echo esc_url( home_url() ); ?>/category/chicken/`

Comment: @leko Yes, its not a good practice. If someone changes the URL structure from the settings page your navigation might break.

Answer (score 5):

home_url is faster and secure than get_option('home')
optionally you can append the argument using home_url function.

Comment: What do you mean by "append the argument using home_url" ? ----- Also, if I need to link to an "About Us" page would I do it like this: `<?php echo esc_url( home_url() ); ?>/about-us/` ----- And is it suggested to use the escape the URL version: `<?php echo esc_url( home_url() ); ?>`

Comment: Argument append example:  
<?php echo home_url( '/blog/' ) ?>  
this will echo: http://example.com/blog/  

we can use the wordpress escape function for any user inserted content, not necesary for wordpress function. But in plugins, template, forms or stuff like this you need to use the escape functions.

Answer (score 2):

I would stick to the function. It is a helper function that not only handles the option retrieval for you but sets http/https and (optionally) appends a path so no need to do the grunt work yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Using wordpress predefined function like home_url() is much safer than getting the raw data using get_option('home');

Answer (score 2):

Yes to both! (Is one faster/is one more secure)

Home_url() is both faster and more secure!

The answer lies in the behavior of each function you reference in the question:

Get_option goes through a controller to find the option with the name given.

While home_url is a built in function that returns the properly formatted url.